# How to turn off tree search in fico xpress ? Couldn't see relevant documentation

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cplex, gurobi, solver

trying to solve a very large problem , using heuremphasis as 3 , cutfreq=0 , scaling =4, run time reduced significantly however ,  solver spends 400 seconds in tree search , but couldn't see any improvement in the solution , so looking for ways to turn it off

Comment: Do you really want to turn off the log or want to stop the solving process? For the second, some criteria like gap or time limit would be helpful.

Comment: don't want and solver to waste time in tree search parameter ,  I want the solver to try some other heurestic

Comment: If you set corresponding parameters for using the heuristics, the solver actually does its capability to solve the problem. If you want to speed up the solving process w.r.t the defined heuristics, you may need to change other parameters and also the current formulation.

Answer (score 4):

Use [MAXNODE](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/HTML/MAXNODE.html) option to limit the tree search.

You might also try setting [HEURSEARCHROOTCUTFREQ](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/HTML/HEURSEARCHROOTCUTFREQ.html) to 1 to run heuristics between each cutting plane round.